# Maintaining a List of React Components then rendering into parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a hypothetical question about maintaining an array of polymorphic React components. Is it possible/good React practice to maintain an array of components that are descendants of a common component, then render them in the container? For instance:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

import GenericBlock from './GenericBlock';
import { BlockTypeA, BlockTypeB, BlockTypeC } from './MyBlocks';

export default class BlockHolder extends React.Component {
    blocks : GenericBlock[] = [ <BlockTypeA />, <BlockTypeB />, <BlockTypeC /> ];

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="workspace">
                {
                    this.blocks
                }
            </div>);
    };
};
```

GenericBlock.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export default class GenericBlock extends React.Component {
    render() { return (<div></div>); }
}
```

MyBlocks.tsx:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

import GenericBlock from './GenericBlock';

class BlockTypeA extends GenericBlock {
    render() { return (<div></div>); }
};

class BlockTypeB extends GenericBlock {
    render() { return (<div></div>); }
};

class BlockTypeC extends GenericBlock {
    render() { return (<div></div>); }
};

export { BlockTypeA, BlockTypeB, BlockTypeC };
```

The above code snippet yields the error: `Objects are not valid as a React child`, but I think it captures the spirit of what I am talking about. Is there a way to make the above scheme work?

I am sure that this question has already been asked and answered, but I can't seem to get the Google Search correct.

**EDIT**:

Added Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-wilson-vb7nn

Now I am encountering a new error: `Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'GenericBlock': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 2 more.`

**EDIT 2**:

Typing the `blocks` array as JSX.Element removes the error and makes everything work, but that doesn't seem like very good practice as `JSX.Element` can be any element, whereas the point of typing it as `GenericBlock` is to ensure that all the elements are descendants of a specific component.

Comment: Just want to comment that after further experimentation on this idea, I would recommend just using composition rather than inheritance to ensure polymorphism (i.e. create a component that conditionally contains your other components, rather than inheriting components from a common component class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in react code, it works perfectly: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-ptolemy-g25ge

no errors, no warnings

```js
import * as React from "react";

import { BlockTypeA, BlockTypeB, BlockTypeC } from "./MyBlocks";

export default class BlockHolder extends React.Component {
  blocks = [
    <BlockTypeA key={1} />,
    <BlockTypeB key={2} />,
    <BlockTypeC key={3} />
  ];

  render() {
    return <div id="workspace">{this.blocks}</div>;
  }
}

import * as React from "react";

export default class GenericBlock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}

import * as React from 'react';

import GenericBlock from './GenericBlock';

class BlockTypeA extends GenericBlock {
    render() { return (<div>A</div>); }
};

class BlockTypeB extends GenericBlock {
    render() { return (<div>B</div>); }
};

class BlockTypeC extends GenericBlock {
    render() { return (<div>C</div>); }
};

export { BlockTypeA, BlockTypeB, BlockTypeC };
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  }
```

Comment: Interesting, that it works on the sandbox and not my environment. The exact same code for me yields the compilation error: `TS2740: Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'BlockTypeA': render, context, and setState.`

Comment: what about versions? react?

Comment: 16.13.1, everything it up to date

Comment: I added dependency section

Comment: what about others?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1"
  }

Comment: Typing the array as JSX.Element removes the error but now the component array is not being rendered: `blocks : JSX.Element[] = [ <BlockTypeA />, ... ]`